# VS2012 VB.NET Designer Errors

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, windows-forms-designer

I was commenting out code in my project and starting getting errors in the designer which stopped me from viewing the page.

After this i decided to put everything back so I was able to run the program again. (Yes, i have made sure to comment everything back)

I am now getting designer errors on some of my pages. Here is the errors and examples.

**Here is the list of errors I am getting:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFX8G.png

**The application does run but if i click on the** *frmMediaDevices1.vb* **page this is the errors that then appears:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZrPE.png

I think it maybe something to do with the Windows.Media.Player that i have referenced in the project on frmMain.vb as when I click the errors the designer code appears highlighting my media player on the page.

Does anyone know how I can maybe refresh the designer? Or know how i can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Form's class must be *the first* in the form's class module.

Problem you described happens if you have files like

```
Form1.designer.vb
Form1.vb
Form1.resx
```

and into file `Form1.vb` which contains `Class Form1` you add class `Class Helper1`. You **can** do it, but class `Form1` must be **kept as the first** class (tompost in code) in `Form1.vb`.

Of course, this also includes the case if you have only one (proper) class in the file (`Class Form1`), but you comment it out.

Just be careful with your commenting and you will avoid that error.